# Wait for ink to dry up

Tags: cups

I have a Canon MB2110 printer with a continuous ink system supply installed. The printer has an automatic duplex feature. Since the rainy season started, every time I print a two sided document, the first page gets all smudged because of the duplex mechanism pulling the paper before the ink is completely dry.

I thought that maybe I could use [Tea4Cups](https://wiki.debian.org/Tea4CUPS) in order to insert some wait before printing the second page. This way, hopefully the ink would have time to dry up.

I would like to know how to use [Tea4Cups](https://wiki.debian.org/Tea4CUPS) to insert such a pause.

Any other suggestions are welcome! But maybe not: use different paper, or use different ink... or use a different printer. :-)

---

1. Although it is against my principles, I have tried Canon software. It is just a binary cups filter and a PPD (that depends on the filter). The installation script just sets up the CUPS using this filter.
2. It might be useful to know that for MAC OS and windows [there is a "Ink Drying Wait Time"](http://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/PrinterDriver/M/MB2100%20series/1.0/EN/PPG/dg-c_duplex.html) option, as @roaima pointed out.

Comment: You'd be better [following the recommendation from Canon](http://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/PrinterDriver/M/MB2100%20series/1.0/EN/PPG/dg-c_duplex.html) to change the drying time directly. Last time I looked the maintenance tool was also available for Linux-based systems.

Comment: Last time I had a Canon printer connected to a Linux machine I also had the GUI-based IJ software installed. This is why I'm suggesting it - not because I've heard of it on Windows/Mac but because _I've used it on a Linux-based system_. On the other hand, I don't have it installed right now so I'm not offering this as a full answer.

Comment: @roaima: I am very sorry for my edit! I got upset because I don't know how to avoid this kind of suggestion. And I did say that "any other suggestions are welcome!". :-)

Anyway, knowing that there is some "setting" is a useful information. Maybe, even without a GUI, I could just add an option to CUPS. I have tried, but I really don't know what I am doing.

The Canon software I downloaded just installs binary CUPS filters and sets up the printer using CUPS.